# Extracting xml tag value for a given subtag-field combination

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

The BZLoans table has the column named LnXML which contains XML data/
The table also has a Loanid column where the loanid is stored. 
Sample data is shown below in the LnXML field in the row where the LoanID = 12345:

```
<Loans>  
<Schedule>
    <PID>4</PID>
           <Amt>2100<dAmt>
</Schedule>
<Schedule>
    <PID>5</PID>
         <Amt>1000</Amt>
</Schedule>
</Loans>
```

The root tag is Loans and below that is the Schedule tag with multiple subtags

I am lookng for a query that will return the value in the Amt tag when the PID tag value and the LoanID value are specified.

For example when PID is specified as 5 and LoanID as 12345, then the query should return,
PID, LoanID, Amt
5.12345.1000

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Ok, so now we know what you want to do but what is the question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am seeking a T-SQL Query that will return the result as shown in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
declare @Loanid int = 12345
declare @PID int = 5

select @PID as PID,
       @Loanid as Loanid,
       L.X.value('.', 'int') as Amt
from BZLoans as B
  cross apply B.LnXML.nodes('/Loans/Schedule[PID = sql:variable("@PID")]/Amt') as L(X)
where B.Loanid = @Loanid
```